# Code doesnt print anything

Tags: python, printing

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
fill-in-the-blanks1.py

"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
p1 

"""

level1 = '''The __1__ command can print out any types of a variable. __2__ defines a function that could be 
called out at any place in the document. A __3__ is a group of strings, variables or numbers. __3__ can also be
printed by the __1__ command. __4__ is the statement of true or false.'''

level2 = '''A ___1___ is created with the def keyword. You specify the inputs a ___1___ takes by
adding ___2___ separated by commas between the parentheses. ___1___ by default return ___3___ if you
don't specify the value to return. ___2___ can be standard data types such as string, number, dictionary,
tuple, and ___4___ or can be more complicated such as objects and lambda functions.'''

level3 = '''__1__ , __2__ , __3__ , all belongs to the if statement. __1__ will be used at the beginning of the
if statement, __2__ will be used in the middle between the __4__ and the __5__ statement. '''
variables1 = ["print", "def", "list", "boolean"]
variables2 = ["function", "parameter", "false", "list"]
variables3 = ["if", "elif", "else", "first"]

d = "__1__"
e = "__2__"
f = "__3__"
g = "__4__"
h = "__5__"
def replacevar(string, variable, inputa, finish):
    string.split()
    while True:
        if inputa == variable[0]:
            string = string.replace(d, inputa)
            finish = ""
            finish = finish.join(string)
            return finish
            break;       

        else:
            print ("Your Answer is incorrect, pls try again")
            return True


level = input("Which level do you want to play? (1, 2 or 3)")
if level == "1":
    print (level1)
    useranswer = input("Please enter the value for variable NO.1: ")
    replacevar(level1, variables1, useranswer, finish1)
    print (finish1)
```

Python code as above, this is just the first part of the program that asks you to fill in the blank and replace the **1**..... with the word you entered if your answer is correct. But when I run the program, after I typed 1, the question showed as expected, but after I typed "print"(without the "") for the answer for the first variable "**1**", it doesn't print the string with replaced words.

Comment: There seems to be something missing, the variable `finish1` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you get over the hurdle of making level 1 work, I believe the structure of your program makes it difficult to get the other levels to work as well without a lot of redundant code.  I've reworked it a bit below to enable the other levels -- see if this gives you any ideas with respect to moving forward with your program:

```
statements = {
    "1": '''The __1__ command can print out any type of a variable. __2__ defines a function that
could be called out at any place in the document. A __3__ is a group of strings, variables or numbers.
__3__ can also be printed by the __1__ command. __4__ is a statement of true or false.''',

    "2": '''A __1__ is created with the def keyword. You specify the inputs a __1__ takes by
adding __2__ separated by commas between the parentheses. __1__ by default return __3__ if you
don't specify the value to return. __2__ can be standard data types such as string, number,
dictionary, tuple, and __4__ or can be more complicated such as objects and lambda functions.''',

    "3": '''__1__ , __2__ , __3__ , all belong to the if statement. __1__ will be used at the beginning
of the if statement, __2__ will be used in the middle between the __4__ and the __5__ statement.''',
}

answers = {
    "1": [("__1__", "print"), ("__2__", "def"), ("__3__", "list"), ("__4__", "boolean")],
    "2": [("__1__", "function"), ("__2__", "parameters"), ("__3__", "false"), ("__4__", "list")],
    "3": [("__1__", "if"), ("__2__", "elif"), ("__3__", "else"), ("__4__", "first")],
}

def replacevar(string, answer, response, blank):

    if response == answer:
        return string.replace(blank, response)

    return None

level = input("Which level do you want to play? (1, 2 or 3) ")

statement = statements[level]

blanks = answers[level]

print(statement)

for (blank, answer) in blanks:
    while True:
        user_answer = input("Please enter the value for blank " + blank + " ")

        finish = replacevar(statement, answer, user_answer, blank)

        if finish is None:
            print("Your Answer is incorrect, please try again")
        else:
            statement = finish
            print(statement)
            break

print("Level completed!")
```

Some specific issues with your code: `replacevar()` has a `break` which will never be reached after a `return`; `replacevar()` sometimes returns a boolean and sometimes a string -- it should return a string or `None`, or it should return `True` or `False`, but don't mix types on return; your main program ignores the result of `replacevar()` which it shouldn't as it sets you up for the next blank; you `split()` the string but fail to save the results of the call so it's a no-op; you call `join()` on a string when it's meant to be called on an array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I also want to know, do none of the python code needs a ";" at the end? And does the spacing before typing the statements matter?

Comment: @AlanLin, the end of statement semicolon is rarely used in Python and rarely used well even when it is.  Avoid it.  Python is somewhat unique in that the spacing/indentation before each line is semantically significant.  It's not so much about how much spacing/indentation as it is about consistency.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue was you were using if level == "1": , replace it with if level == 1: and it worked.

```
   """
    fill-in-the-blanks1.py

    """

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
p1 

"""

level1 = '''The __1__ command can print out any types of a variable. __2__ defines a function that could be 
called out at any place in the document. A __3__ is a group of strings, variables or numbers. __3__ can also be
printed by the __1__ command. __4__ is the statement of true or false.'''

level2 = '''A ___1___ is created with the def keyword. You specify the inputs a ___1___ takes by
adding ___2___ separated by commas between the parentheses. ___1___ by default return ___3___ if you
don't specify the value to return. ___2___ can be standard data types such as string, number, dictionary,
tuple, and ___4___ or can be more complicated such as objects and lambda functions.'''

level3 = '''__1__ , __2__ , __3__ , all belongs to the if statement. __1__ will be used at the beginning of the
if statement, __2__ will be used in the middle between the __4__ and the __5__ statement. '''
variables1 = ["print", "def", "list", "boolean"]
variables2 = ["function", "parameter", "false", "list"]
variables3 = ["if", "elif", "else", "first"]

d = "__1__"
e = "__2__"
f = "__3__"
g = "__4__"
h = "__5__"
def replacevar(string, variable, inputa, finish):
    string.split()
    while True:
        if inputa == variable[0]:
            string = string.replace(d, inputa)
            finish = ""
            finish = finish.join(string)
            return finish
            break;       

        else:
            print ("Your Answer is incorrect, pls try again")
            return True


level = input("Which level do you want to play? (1, 2 or 3)")
if level == 1:
    print (level1)
    useranswer = input("Please enter the value for variable NO.1: ")
    replacevar(level1, variables1, useranswer, finish1)
    print (finish1)
```

Comment: level 1 takes int as input and you were using "1" which becomes character so it fulfill if condition so if condition was not executed.